# Can't enable 'sa' account in SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, sql

I'm trying to enable 'sa' account in SQL Server 2008 through the MS SQL Server Management Studio Express. When I set the properties through the 'Properties' section of the login and click Ok, there are no error messages! But when I revisit the properties, password is rolled back to the previous one.

[image]

[image]

Ultimately can't access the account!

[image]

Comment: sorry if you have checked this but does the user you are making the changes as have the sysadmin privilege?

Comment: @Time Alexander I run the MSSQLSMSE as administrator, and log to windows as administrator!

Comment: [Check your logs and see what the error state is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) to get a better idea of the problem.  And post it here if you want help.

Comment: Got the issue solved with this --> [link](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-authentication-enabling.html)

Comment: not sure how that solved it when your screenshots show the account is enabled already?

Comment: @TimAlexander I'm not sure either as I'm no expert of SQL Server, but I can assure you it worked. I'm using this login now, with no issues at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this issue solved by enabling "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" in the server properties.

[image]

Got help from [this article](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-authentication-enabling.html).